# How to remove data memeber form validtion summary in Silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

In SilverLight Validation summary shows error in two parts one is data member name and the other is error message.
Data member is the binding source Property name .I just don't want to show the datamember name.

How can i remove this from validation summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution .

By using  **DisplayAttribute** of **DataAnnotations** we can change the display name of the viewmodel property.

For Example:

```
  [Display(Name="First Name")]
  public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {       
                firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");

        }
    }
```

By setting Display now ValidationSummary will Show Display attribute name instead of propertyName.
And if you don't want to show any name just errors in Summary just set Display attribute as [Display(Name="")]